# Magento Media Multi Store Setup

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have recently setup up multiple stores with Magento 1.7 and have given them both independent skins and media folders. The problem is now when I upload a category image the file gets uploaded to the first stores media folder and is unable to be referenced by the second store.

To rectify this I have now made them share the same media folder, which for the moment, I can't for see a problem with, but I am still wondering if anyone knows how to set this up?

Comment: I didn't try but perhaps it helps you.Goto current configuration scope and select your current webiste and on web (Under the General tab ) change the media path to your new one

Comment: They both have different media paths, but when you upload an image in the backend it gets saved in just one of the folders

Comment: From where you are uploading ? configuration or somewhere else ?

Comment: uploading an image for a category

Answer (score 0):

In magento you can set different media url for every store, but there is no standard way for setting up different media folder every store. Try to this link: 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4373/every-store-have-their-own-media-folder/4389#4389